# Installed 16.04 lts now how to make it boot first or have a option when booting

Tags: boot

I don't have a option when booting, I am running Windows 8 and want to get into ubuntu a bit before full conversion. I though that it did not actually install so I used my external drive to start installing again but the installer said I already have it installed. Afterwards ubuntu booted as if in the demo live again with the install 16.04 1 LTS on the home screen. Not sure if that is just a misunderstanding or not

Comment: Are dual booting with windows 8 ?

Comment: Do you still have the drive / disk you used for installation connected ? If so, remove it.

Answer (score 0):

You should go to BIOS, go to the option Boot, put ubuntu to the first element and windows the second. Probabily the error is it but if not found after this, put an answer here.

Good luck!

Comment: I went to bios and ubuntu was not a option, I then disabled fast startup and am reinstalling.